# How to append a formgroup to another?

Tags: angular, forms, angular6, formgroups

I have two formgroups :`firstFormGroup` and `secondFormGroup`

`firstFormGroup` is in mat step 1 and `secondFormGroup` is in mat step 2.
Now while posting it to the backend, I want to append `secondFormGroup` to the `firstFormGroup`

How to achieve this?

Comment: When you ask the question here then you have to provide some snippets of your code so can others will get idea and give the solution.

Comment: As you know formGroup is nothing but the pair of key: value. so, you can easily cancat two object in single one, like Object.assign({},firstFormGroup.value,secondFormGroup.value);

Answer (score 1):

You can get values from these forms and merge them into one dictionary using `Object.assign`.

```
const data = Object.assign({}, firstFormGroup.value, secondFormFroup.value);
```

Also, you can use nested form groups

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

  form = new FormGroup({
    first: new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('')
    }),
    second: new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl('')
    })
  });
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

then in template

```
<form [formGroup]="form.get('first')"></form>
<form [formGroup]="form.get('second')"></form>
```

this way you will not loose any data even if you have controls with the same key on multiple steps and you have only one form to work with and validate.